# finding the source of random HTML tags written to web page

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a very strange problem with a web page. The source HTML code is correct, but when I use Chrome's developer tools to inspect the page (font is much smaller than it should be), I find 8 HTML small tags added to my code. These tags do not exist in the source code, however. So, I suspect that I have a Javascript file writing these tags to the page. To add to the mystery, I do not have this problem on our dev or QA servers, only in production.

How can I find the source of these  tags on this page? I have no idea even if this is a script causing the problem. To make matters worse, this is not a page I built, but rather inherited, and the state of the HTML and Javascript code is horrendous. This page has a tangled web of Javascript files, so it is really difficult for me to debug this problem.

any help, tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One thing you could do would be to comment out different JS files until the small tags stop appearing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right click on parent node and select `Break on` -> `subtree modifications`. This will create a breakpoint when child nodes change. Then in Sources tab, where it breaks you can see the CallStack, all methods called to get that point.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom